# undo commits associated with everything but one file

Tags: git, github, fork, commit

I forked a repository and created a file I want to later combine with the original repo.

However, along the way I was messing around and edited/created/moved other unrelated files that made their way into the commits.

Now that the important file is ready to combine with the original repo, i have all these bad commits from before unrelated to the file.

Is there some way to undo all changes except to a specific file, back to some point in the past?

---

For reference, I added a chrome-storage-sync.js file to my fork of the lawnchair wrapper for html5/js client side storage

https://github.com/hayksaakian/lawnchair

my pull request with the undesirable commits:

https://github.com/brianleroux/lawnchair/pull/150

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to answer my question:

http://jasonrudolph.com/blog/2009/02/25/git-tip-how-to-merge-specific-files-from-another-branch/

Comment: Yes, using `git checkout` of the file will allow you to commit a change that reverts your changes to that file. If you want to erase any history of your changes, you'd need to rewrite history with something like `git-rebase`.